# Android - Is ViewHolder pattern automatically implemented in CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, database, android-cursoradapter

I always use `ViewHolder` pattern in my custom `ArrayAdapter` classes. However, in `CursorAdapter` the `getView()` method is not mandatory required to be overridden , but has the `bindView` and `newView` methods.

My question is - does `CursorAdapter` re-uses views by internally implementing the `ViewHolder` pattern or it needs to be coded as we normally do in custom `ArrayAdapter`? If it needs to be coded, what is the correct way to do it?

**Update**

I'm using `android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> My question is - does CursorAdapter re-uses views by internally
>   implementing the ViewHolder pattern or it needs to be coded as we
>   normally do in custom ArrayAdapter?

I'm not sure at what do you refer by the `ViewHolder` pattern. If you are referring to having a helper class to cache looking for view each time(and setting it as a tag for the row `View`) then the answer is no. If you want to implement this pattern you'll need to setup the holder(look for the views in the row view with `findViewById`) in the `newView` method and then set it as the tag for the row view. Then in the `bindView` method you can call `getTag`, retrieve the holder and use it. An example:

```
// custom CursorAdapter ...

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = ((LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(
                R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.v1 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.v1);
        holder.v2 = rowView.findViewById(R.id.v2);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        // use the holder filled with views
        // hlder.v1.setSomething
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        View v1, v2;
    }
// ...
```

If you are referring to the `convertView` being reused(like in non `Cursor` based adapters) then the answer is yes, the `getView` method implements this pattern, you just need to implement the `newView` and `bindView` methods and you're guaranteed to get a view which was recycled(if possible at that moment).

Comment: @Mahendra So it was the first case. No, the holder pattern isn't implemented in `CursorAdapter`(from the SDK or the compatibility package).

Comment: My query is more about 'coding the `Holder` in custom adapter or is it not required'? I see the `CursorAdapter` class also has the `getView` method..

Comment: @Mahendra Implementing the holder is up to you. You'll get a performance improvement but it not that much as using the `convertView`. I've edited my answer with a small example.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't indicated whether you are using the platform version or the support library version of `CursorAdapter`.  In either case, Android is open source, so you can look for yourself!

[android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.java)
[android.widget.CursorAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java)

If you're using Chrome, the [Android SDK Reference Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-sdk-reference-sea/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin) component is super-helpful!

Comment: I udpated my question... I'm using the support library version