# Use Loader to load listview data in backgroud for smooth scrolling

Tags: android

I have a custom listview which has more child views . When I scroll the listview it scrolls very slow leading to avoid the use of the application. I am very much new to android ,please help me how to load the data in background thread , so that the listview scrolls smooth

SearchListActivity.java

```
public class SearchListActivity extends ListActivity{

    String from[];
    static String longClickValue;
    int to[];   
    static String name="",birthdate="",westerZodiac="",turnsAge="",nextBD="",eventType="";
    static Bitmap bitMap=null;
    //CustomCursorAdapter adapter;
    CustomSimpleCursor adapter;

    TextView emptyView;
    Cursor cursor=null;
    CursorLoader cursorLoader=null;
    ImageView imageV;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.search_list_activity);      

        cursorLoader=new CursorLoader(this,BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null,null);

        cursor=cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        from=new String[]{BirthdayProvider.NAME,BirthdayProvider.NUMBER,BirthdayProvider.CATEGORY,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_TYPE,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_DAY,BirthdayProvider.WESTERN_ZODIAC};

        to=new int[]{R.id.title_name,R.id.sub_title_contact_number,R.id.sub_title_category,R.id.txtview_type_of_reminder,R.id.sub_title_birthdate,R.id.txtview_zodiac};

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {         
            adapter=new CustomSimpleCursor(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to);
            getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        else
        {
            emptyView=(TextView)getListView().findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        }   

        getListView().setLongClickable(true);

        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int index, long arg3) {
                TextView txtName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title_name);
                name=txtName.getText().toString();


                imageV=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
                //imageV.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rings_icon));

                ImageView imgView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                bitMap=((BitmapDrawable)imgView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                TextView label=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_contact_number);

                longClickValue=label.getText().toString();

                Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),ContactInfoMoreOption.class);
                intent.putExtra("intentType","SearchListActivity");
                intent.putExtra("longClickValue",longClickValue);
                intent.putExtra("imgObj",imageV.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });     

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        TextView txtName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title_name);
        name=txtName.getText().toString();

        ImageView imgView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        bitMap=((BitmapDrawable)imgView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        TextView txtBirthdate=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_birthdate);
        birthdate=txtBirthdate.getText().toString();

        TextView txtTurnsAge=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtview_turns);
        turnsAge=txtTurnsAge.getText().toString();

        TextView txtWesterZodiac=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtview_zodiac);
        westerZodiac=txtWesterZodiac.getText().toString();

        TextView txtNextBD=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtview_next_bd);
        nextBD=txtNextBD.getText().toString();

        TextView txtEventType=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtview_type_of_reminder);
        eventType=txtEventType.getText().toString();

        Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),ContactInfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

CustomSimpleCursor.java

```
public class CustomSimpleCursor extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    Typeface font;
    TextView txtDaysRemainigValue,txtTurnsAge;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CustomSimpleCursor(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);            

            String todayBD = null;

            //Zodiac icon
            try {
                    ImageView thumbZodiacIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
                    InputStream is = context.getResources().getAssets().open(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BirthdayProvider.ZODIAC_ICON)));
                    Bitmap bit = /*BirthdayCalculation.ShrinkBitmap(is,200, 200);*/BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    thumbZodiacIcon.setImageBitmap(bit);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }

         // Event icon 
            try {
                    ImageView thumbEventIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
                    InputStream is = context.getResources().getAssets().open(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_ICON)));
                    Bitmap bit =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    thumbEventIcon.setImageBitmap(bit);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            //Contact photo
            try {
                ImageView thumbContact = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                byte bitmapData[]=cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.PHOTO));   
                Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.length);
                thumbContact.setImageBitmap(bit);

                /*Animation localAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.fadein_image);
                thumbContact.startAnimation(localAnimation);*/

        } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Days remaining for BirthDay  

         txtDaysRemainigValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_days_left);

         String year=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_YEAR));
         String month=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_MONTH));  
         String date=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_DATE));
         String remainingDays=BirthdayCalculation.getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(year, month, date);

          Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
          int CMonth=(today.get(Calendar.MONDAY)+1);
          int CDate=(today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


          txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#990000"));
          txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 27);

          //checking whether the BD is on TODAY

          if (remainingDays.equals("1") && (CDate==Integer.parseInt(date) && (CMonth)==Integer.parseInt(month))) {

              Log.v("else if executed","else if executed");
              Log.v("Remainin Days",remainingDays+" = Custom month"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.NAME))+"="+(CMonth)+"="+month);
             Log.v("Remainin Days",remainingDays+" = Custom date"+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.NAME))+"="+CDate+"="+date);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00CC33"));
            remainingDays="today".toLowerCase();
        }

          //checking whether the BD is on TOMORROW
          else if (remainingDays.equals("1")) {

             Log.v("Remainin Days",remainingDays+" = Custom month"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.NAME))+"="+(CMonth)+"="+month);
             Log.v("Remainin Days",remainingDays+" = Custom date"+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.NAME))+"="+CDate+"="+date);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
            remainingDays="tomorrow".toLowerCase();
        }


        //checking how many days remaining BD
          else{
              remainingDays=BirthdayCalculation.getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(year, month, date);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 27);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#990000"));

          }
          txtDaysRemainigValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_days_left);    
          font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "DS_DIGIB.ttf");
          txtDaysRemainigValue.setTypeface(font);

          //Log.v("Custom month",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.NAME))+"="+(CMonth)+"="+month);
          //Log.v("Custom date", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.NAME))+"="+CDate+"="+date);
          txtDaysRemainigValue.setText(remainingDays);

      //Turns age
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "athletic.ttf");
        txtTurnsAge=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_turns);   
        //txtTurnsAge.setTypeface(font);
        String turnsAge=BirthdayCalculation.getAge(Integer.parseInt(year),Integer.parseInt(month),Integer.parseInt(date));
        txtTurnsAge.setText(turnsAge);


      //Event week
        try {

            TextView txtEventWeek=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_next_bd);       
            String eventWeek=BirthdayCalculation.getDayOfWeek(year, month, date);
            font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Comic Sans.ttf");
            txtEventWeek.setTypeface(font);
            txtEventWeek.setText(eventWeek);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 



        // Contact Name

        TextView txtNumber=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_contact_number);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto_Light.ttf");
        txtNumber.setTypeface(font);

        TextView txtBirtgDay=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_birthdate);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto_Light.ttf");
        txtBirtgDay.setTypeface(font);


        TextView txtZodiac=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto_Light.ttf");
        txtZodiac.setTypeface(font);

        TextView txtZodiacValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_zodiac);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Comic Sans.ttf");
        txtZodiacValue.setTypeface(font);


        TextView txtNextBD=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto_Light.ttf");
        txtNextBD.setTypeface(font);


        TextView txtTurnsAge=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image_arrow);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "athletic.ttf");
        txtTurnsAge.setTypeface(font);

        TextView txtDayRemainig=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView04);    
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "athletic.ttf");
        txtDayRemainig.setTypeface(font);





        TextView txtTurnsAgeValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_turns);    
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "DS_DIGIB.ttf");
        txtTurnsAgeValue.setTypeface(font);

    }   
}
```

Comment: How many rows in your db table? Can you put code of CustomSimpleCursor?

Comment: you mean ... coloumn or rows ??

Comment: CustomSimpleCursor.java posted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve speed of your listview your must complete next steps:

1. Use ViewHolder patter because view.findViewById is slow operation.
2. You can load all needed typeface before. Your every time load same typefaces. For example `Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto_Light.ttf")`
3. You can load all zodiac icon before because i think that zodiac icon has limit count
4. if photo is big image than you can load image from another thread.

I think it is enough.

Comment: Can u give example of ViewHolder patter

Comment: For example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860795/android-is-viewholder-pattern-automatically-implemented-in-cursoradapter

Comment: " You can load all needed typeface before "--- means I should load it in the constructor of CustomSimpleCursor ??

Comment: I wrote a fresh code inside getView()..I am confused about the cursor ,because getView() doesn't supplies cursor parameter

Comment: I shifted the code to bindView().. Thanks man ..Your answer really helped me

Answer (score 0):

according to your code try this

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
 switch (view.getId) {
   case R.id.ImageView01:
    // your code here
   break;
   case R.id.ImageView02:
   // your code here
   break;

  }
}
```

Comment: but what about Asynk Task or Loader to load data in background thread