# Android Studio - TabHost refresh tab content

Tags: android, listview, tabs

please help me..

ok here is my problem. i use tabhost and i have 3 tabs.

compose of SONG LIST, NEW SONGS and FAVORITES

here is the code of the tabhost..

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

        final TabHost host = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();

        dbHelper = new FragmentOne_DbAdapter(getActivity());
        dbHelper.open();
        //Clean all data
        //dbHelper.deleteAllPlayer1();
        //Add some data
        dbHelper.insertPlayer1Songlist();
        //Generate ListView from SQLite Database

        //Tab 1
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("SONG LIST");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("SONG LIST");
        host.addTab(spec);

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slPlayer1ListView);
            player1ESearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.player1Search);
            ImageButton dplayer1ESearch=(ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            dplayer1ESearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    player1ESearch.setText("");
                }
            });
            displayPlayer1ListView();

        //Tab 2
        spec = host.newTabSpec("NEW SONGS");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("NEW SONGS");
        host.addTab(spec);

            listViewNew = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slPlayer1NewListView);
            displayPlayer1NewListView();

        //Tab 3
        spec = host.newTabSpec("FAVORITES");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("FAVORITES");
        host.addTab(spec);



        return rootView;
    }
```

in my tab **SONG LIST**, i display list from database and set it to adapter..

in this part of the code..

```
private void displayPlayer1ListView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllPlayer1();

        FragmentOneAdapter = new FragmentOne_Adapter(getActivity(), cursor, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(FragmentOneAdapter);

        player1ESearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                FragmentOneAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

        FragmentOneAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.fetchPlayer1ByTitle(constraint.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

and here is my adapter bindview..

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        final int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
        String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("artist"));
        String volume = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("volume"));
        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"));
        final String favorite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("favorite"));
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("number"));

        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        holder.txtTitle.setText(title);
        holder.txtArtist.setText(artist);
        holder.txtVolume.setText(volume);
        holder.txtNumber.setText(number);

        if (type.matches("1")) {
            holder.buttonType.setImageResource(R.drawable.newsong);
        } else if (type.matches("2")) {
            holder.buttonType.setImageResource(R.drawable.practice);
        } else if (type.matches("0")) {
            holder.buttonType.setImageResource(R.drawable.none);
        }

        if (favorite.matches("0")) {
            holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
        } else {
            if (favorite.matches("1")) {
                holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
            } else {
                holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
            }
        }

        holder.buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (arg0 != null) {
                    FragmentOne_DbAdapter database = new FragmentOne_DbAdapter(context);
                    database.open();
                    if (favorite.matches("0")) {
                        database.updateItemFavorite(_id, "1");
                        holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
                    } else if (favorite.matches("1")) {
                        database.updateItemFavorite(_id, "0");
                        holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                    }
                }
                FragmentOne_Adapter.this.changeCursor(dbHelper.fetchAllPlayer1());

            }
        });

    }
```

as you can see in my adapter i have **database.updateItemFavorite**, in this part, this is where i update field in database if it is favorite it will set to 1 and the imageview resource will be heartred.

now my second is **NEW SONGS**

in the second tab i display new songs in this part of the code..

```
private void displayPlayer1NewListView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllPlayer1New();
        FragmentOneAdapterNew = new FragmentOne_AdapterNew(getActivity(), cursor, 0);
        listViewNew.setAdapter(FragmentOneAdapterNew);
    }
```

here is the bindview for my new song..

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        final int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
        String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("artist"));
        String volume = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("volume"));
        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"));
        final String favorite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("favorite"));
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("number"));

        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        holder.txtTitle.setText(title);
        holder.txtArtist.setText(artist);
        holder.txtVolume.setText(volume);
        holder.txtNumber.setText(number);

        if (type.matches("1")) {
            holder.buttonType.setImageResource(R.drawable.newsong);
        } else if (type.matches("2")) {
            holder.buttonType.setImageResource(R.drawable.practice);
        } else if (type.matches("0")) {
            holder.buttonType.setImageResource(R.drawable.none);
        }

        if (favorite.matches("0")) {
            holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
        } else {
            if (favorite.matches("1")) {
                holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
            } else {
                holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
            }
        }

        holder.buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (arg0 != null) {
                    FragmentOne_DbAdapter database = new FragmentOne_DbAdapter(context);
                    database.open();
                    if (favorite.matches("0")) {
                        database.updateItemFavorite(_id, "1");
                        holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
                    } else if (favorite.matches("1")) {
                        database.updateItemFavorite(_id, "0");
                        holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                    }
                }
                FragmentOne_AdapterNew.this.changeCursor(dbHelper.fetchAllPlayer1New());
            }
        });

    }
```

in my SONG LIST, after i click favorite imagebutton. it update my favorite field to 1 and set resource to heartred.

now my problem is when i click the tab NEW SONGS. the updated favorite from SONG LIST should also appear in my NEW SONGS list.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your second tabs new Song Override this method if you are using fragment.

```
   @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser){
          displayPlayer1NewListView() ;
        }
    }
```

This method is call when your 2nd tabs fragment is visible on screen and refresh this list.

Comment: sorry im new to android.. please see update.. can you help me where to put that code?

Comment: Override setUserVisibleHintin in new songs fragment. in your new songs fragment refresh new songs in setUserVisibleHint method.

Comment: hi @asim, i dont use fragment for my tab content.. i just use linearlayout.. please help me.. thanks..

Comment: call displayPlayer1NewListView() at the end of buttonHeart, pass instance of class in adapter contractor. FragmentOneAdapterNew = new FragmentOne_AdapterNew(getActivity(), cursor, 0,this). and in buttonHeart click call this method with instance.displayPlayer1NewListView(); this will refresh your new song list each time you click on heart button.

Comment: sorry asim im new to android.. can you please update your answer.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

for those who encounter this problem.. i found an answer..

```
host.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

                int i = host.getCurrentTab();
                if (i == 0) {
                    displayPlayer1ListView();
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    displayPlayer1NewListView();
                }
            }
        });
```